# Submit Form and create user - Worpress + Google Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, google-forms

I have a user registration form simple HTML no plugin and I would like to make it create a user in worpress (this part works) and submit the form as google form with no redirect (only the message displayed by the form). What can be the solutions?

I have tried to recreate the same form in google format and hidden, but the submit button does not submit and if it does the form was empty as it was submitted too late.

This part is the HTML form

```
function registration_form( $username, $password, $email, $first_name, $last_name ){
echo '
 <form action="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '" method="post">
 <div>
 <label for="firstname">Jméno <strong>*</strong></label>
 <input type="text" name="fname" required id="name" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['fname']) ? $first_name : null ) . '">
 </div>
 
 <div>
 <label for="website">Příjmení <strong>*</strong></label>
 <input type="text" name="lname" required id="lastname" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['lname']) ? $last_name : null ) . '">
 </div>
 
   <div>
 <label for="email">Datum narození <strong>*</strong></label>
 <input type="date" name="bday" required id="bday" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['bday']) ? $birthday : null ) . '">
 </div>
 
  <div>
 <label for="email">E-mail <strong>*</strong></label>
 <input type="email" name="email" required id="email" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['email']) ? $email : null ) . '">
 </div>
 
   <div>
 <input type="text" name="email1" required id="email1" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['email1']) ? $email1 : null ) . '" placeholder="Potvrzení emailu">
 </div>
 
  <div>
 <label for="email">Telefon <strong>*</strong></label>
 <input type="text" name="telefon" required id="telefon" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['telefon']) ? $phone : null ) . '">
 
 <br><br><br><br>
 <div>
 <label for="username">Přihlašovací jméno <strong>*</strong></label>
 <input type="text" name="username" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['username'] ) ? $username : null ) . '" placeholder="Minimálně 4 znaky. Pouze písmena a čísla.">
 </div>
 
 <div>
 <label for="password">Heslo <strong>*</strong></label>
 <input type="password" name="password" value="' . ( isset( $_POST['password'] ) ? $password : null ) . '" placeholder="Minimálně 5 znaků">
 </div>

 <div align="center"><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registrovat se"/>
</div></form>
 ';
}
```

Checking for errors and validating form

```
function registration_validation( $username, $password, $email, $first_name, $last_name ) {

global $reg_errors;
 $reg_errors = new WP_Error;

//Check empty fields
 if ( empty( $username ) || empty( $password ) || empty( $email )) {
 $reg_errors->add('field', 'Prosím vyplňte povinné informace.');
 }

 //Check user name lenght greater than 4 character.
 if ( 4 > strlen( $username ) ) {
 $reg_errors->add( 'username_length', 'Přihlašovací jméno je příliš krátké: 4 znaky nejméně' );
 }

//Check user name is exists
 if ( username_exists( $username ) ){
 $reg_errors->add('user_name', 'Již existuje uživatel se stejným uživatelským jménem. Prosím, zvolte si jiné.');
 }

//validate wp user name
 if ( ! validate_username( $username ) ) {
 $reg_errors->add( 'username_invalid', 'Sorry, the username you entered is not valid' );
 }

//check password lengh 
 if ( 5 > strlen( $password ) ) {
 $reg_errors->add( 'password', 'Heslo musí mít nejméně 5 znaků.' );
 }

//check email is correct email
 if ( !is_email( $email ) ) {
 $reg_errors->add( 'email_invalid', 'Email není správný' );
 }
    
 // check email already in use or not
 if ( email_exists( $email ) ) {
 $reg_errors->add( 'email', 'Již existuje uživatel se stejným emailem.' );
 }


if ( is_wp_error( $reg_errors ) ) {
 foreach ( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() as $error ) {
 echo '<div class="zaloha">';
 echo '<strong>ERROR</strong>:';
 echo $error . '<br/>';
 echo '</div>'; 
 }
 }
}

function complete_registration() {
 global $reg_errors, $username, $password, $email, $first_name, $last_name
 if ( 1 > count( $reg_errors->get_error_messages() ) ) {
 $userdata = array(
 'user_login' => $username,
 'user_email' => $email,
 'user_pass' => $password,
 'first_name' => $first_name,
 'last_name' => $last_name,
 'nickname' => $nickname, 
 );

 $user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
 echo '<div class = "zaloha">Vaše registrace proběhla úspěšně.</div><br>'; 
 }
}

function registration_function() {
global $reg_errors, $username, $password, $email, $first_name, $last_name;

if ( isset($_POST['submit'] ) ) {
 registration_validation(
 $_POST['username'],
 $_POST['password'],
 $_POST['email'],
 $_POST['fname'],
 $_POST['lname'],
 $_POST['nickname'] );
    
 
 // call @function complete_registration to create the user only when no WP_error is found
 complete_registration($username, $password, $email, $first_name, $last_name);
}
 
 registration_form( $username, $password, $email, $first_name, $last_name);
}
```

EDIT
As suggested in the comments, I have used CUrl to automatically submit the form with a redirect once the form is submitted to not display the Google confirmation page.

Comment: Use curl to submit data to google forms

Comment: @Ahmad can you please explain a little further, I am quite new to all this php and coding experience. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have control over WordPress by looking at your code.
Here's 1 way of doing it:

1. Install the [Google sheets integration Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpgsi/.).
2. Follow the plugin's step-by-step instructions to get the credentials from google.
3. Go to `Spreadsheet Integrations > Add New Integration`
4. Add Title, In the data source select `WordPress New User`, and in Sheets & worksheets select the sheet where you want the data to go.

Why I suggested using this plugin is that it's making lives easier and Google forms finally put data in Google sheets.

Let me know if this helps or if you need some other way.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. The reason goimg through G Forms was to send an email with pdf files which will be triggered by a new reply in the form. Is there a way to do it when the data arrives from the table at once? I just need new users that passed through the registration and were not created in the back end.

Comment: Yes, there's an easy way to send over the PDFs when a new user is registered in WordPress, instead of doing it with the Google Sheets data.  But i didn't get this: "I just need new users that passed through the registration and were not created in the back end." Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: Hey, I have made the Curl option work. I wanted the pdfs to be sent only to users who register via the registration form and not the users who will be entered manually.

Comment: Good to know you resolved it. To target users who register via register form and not who are entered manually you can use "user_reguster" hook in wordpress. Also, It'd be great if you could edit your question and add a solution block at the very end. It'll help others.